# Question doesn't meet the quality standards

Tags: support, asking-questions

I'm trying to ask a question and I get an error: "Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
It does not meet our quality standards."

How can I know what standard exactly do I violate in order to successfully submit my question?

Comment: A good point to start is the [faq].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read through your question again and make sure that it is using correct use of English, with actual sentences.  Also make sure that you are providing a clear title and sufficient detail in the question.

While exact details are not given out to prevent people working around this check, you can find a bit more information [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards/92075#92075).